# Text highlight with mouse actions in selenium with java not working

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Using selenium and java, I need to highlight the below text using a mouse click and move, After highlighting, the text I can see another popup and I need to do some validation on that popup.

```
<h2 class="lstw">16.1 This is sample text, another, and heading</h2>
```

This is my current code and it is not working sometimes.  **Please note KeyDown or set CSS through javascript is cannot use here.**

```
public boolean userMoveHighlightText(String text){
    String secName = "//h2[text()='"+text+"']";
    getFrame(); // switch to iframe
    By element = getLocator(secName, BY_TYPE.BY_XPATH);
    Actions action = new Actions(getWebDriver());
    WebElement content = $(element);
    
    action.moveToElement(content, 0, 0).clickAndHold().moveToElement(content, content.getSize().getWidth() / 2, content.getSize().getHeight() / 2);
    action.release().build().perform();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: We are missing debugging details. Please share your actual code including a link to that web page and clear description what are you exactly trying to do there.

Comment: I'm trying to highlight the text using a mouse click and there is no error on that, Since the application cannot access to public, I shared the element and it is inside the IFrame, also this is working on sometimes

Answer (score 1):

Replace the below code with the recommended:

```
action.moveToElement(content, 0, 0).clickAndHold().moveToElement(content, content.getSize().getWidth() / 2, content.getSize().getHeight() / 2);
```

**Recommended:**

```
 action.moveToElement(content, 0, 0).build().perform()
//implicit wait 
 action.clickAndHold().moveToElement(content, content.getSize().getWidth() / 2, content.getSize().getHeight() / 2).release().build().perform();
```

Comment: I tried above but still the same issue, content does not highlight.